# How do i multiple sort an array per column for all lines ? (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have created a var rows to generate a csv.
I would like to sort the content according 2 columns : DATE and TIME.

```
DATE;TIME;ID;FACE;TOTAL;VAL1;VAL2;
07/05/2019;14:11:07;3234;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;
07/05/2019;**16:11:07**;1779;0.00000019;2.00;-0.00000019;0;
07/05/2019;14:11:06;4120;0.00000304;2.00;0.00000304;1;
26/05/2019;**06:32:39**;2167;0.00000015;2.00;-0.00000015;0;
26/05/2019;06:32:38;5152;0.00000015;2.00;0.00000015;1;
**07/05/2019**;14:11:18;7949;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;
```

result expected :

```
DATE;TIME;ID;FACE;TOTAL;VAL1;VAL2;
07/05/2019;14:11:06;4120;0.00000304;2.00;0.00000304;1;
07/05/2019;14:11:07;3234;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;
07/05/2019;14:11:18;7949;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;
07/05/2019;16:11:07;1779;0.00000019;2.00;-0.00000019;0;
26/05/2019;06:32:38;2167;0.00000015;2.00;-0.00000015;0;
26/05/2019;06:32:39;5152;0.00000015;2.00;0.00000015;1;
```

```
var lines = rows.split('\n');
for(var loop = 0; loop < lines.length; loop++){
if (parseFloat(prev) > 0){val2= 1;}else {val2 = 0;}
(....)
lines[loop] = lines[loop].replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s+)/gm,"").trim() + val1 + ";" + val2 + ";";
}
rows = lines.join('\n');
```

because it is complicated to use my array lines, I was thinking about using the index array properties. But lines is not considered as an array, so forEach is not usable.

```
var result = lines.reduce(function(r, a) {
        a.forEach(function(s, i) {
        var key = i === 0 ? 'headers' : 'col' + i;              
        r[key] || (r[key] = []); 
        r[key].push(s);
        });
        return r;
        }, {});

function compare(r,x,col) {
    if (r[x].col< r[x+1].col) return -1;
    if (r[x].col > r[x+1].col) return 1;
    return 0;
}
for(var loop = 0; loop < r.length; loop++){
        result.sort(compare(r,loop,col1));
        result.sort(compare(r,loop,col2));
}
```

How to have the double sorting criterias applied and get the rows as expected in this array?

my code is used on google chrome. Some functions like prototype don't work (or filter...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```js
const data = "07/05/2019;14:11:07;3234;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;\n07/05/2019;16:11:07;1779;0.00000019;2.00;-0.00000019;0;\n07/05/2019;14:11:06;4120;0.00000304;2.00;0.00000304;1;\n26/05/2019;06:32:39;2167;0.00000015;2.00;-0.00000015;0;\n26/05/2019;06:32:38;5152;0.00000015;2.00;0.00000015;1;\n07/05/2019;14:11:18;7949;0.00000038;2.00;-0.00000038;0;"

// Convert to array of arrays
let dataArrays = data.split('\n').map(x => x.split(';'))

let extractDate = arr => {
  let dateParts = arr[0].split('/') // get the date parts array
  let [dd,mm,yyyy] = dateParts     // get the actual dd/mm/yyyy
  let [date, time] = arr          // we only care about the date time for the date
  return new Date(`${mm}/${dd}/${yyyy} ${time}`) // return valid date for the sort
}

// perform the actual sort 
let result = dataArrays.sort((a,b) => extractDate(a) - extractDate(b))

console.log(result.map(x => x.join(';')).join('\n')) // join back to same format
```

Where the idea is to convert the `dd/mm/yyyy` to a valid date per each row and then use [Array.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to sort the rows. Once rows are sorted you can convert back to one string via [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) etc.

Comment: Woaaa, amazing result, worked perfectly, 
thank you very much !

just one thing, how can I get again the ";" between each field ?
26/05/2019;06:32:38;5152;0.00000015;2.00;0.00000015;1; ?

Comment: Updated with the last `map` to add the `;'.